# how to link openni library through the "CMakeLists.txt" file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ROS groovy and openni library in the ARM chip. Now I want to use openni library fouction , but I do not know how to link openni library through the "CMakeLists.txt" file. I used "target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} OpenNI)",but it can not link openni founction.Who can tell me how to link openni and write cmake file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56403/how-to-link-openni-library-through-the-%22cmakelists.txt%22-file/) by [Robin Hu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3839/robin-hu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2013-02-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming that ROS Groovy uses OpenNI v1.*, as I presume (don't have an installation handy), try something along these lines:

```
pkg_check_modules (LIBUSB REQUIRED libusb-1.0)
include_directories (${LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories (${LIBUSB_LIBRARY_DIRS})

FIND_PATH(OPEN_NI_INCLUDE "XnOpenNI.h" "OpenNIConfig.h" HINTS "$ENV{OPEN_NI_INCLUDE}" "/usr/include/ni" "/usr/include/openni" "/opt/ros/groovy/include/openni_camera")
FIND_LIBRARY(OPEN_NI_LIBRARY NAMES OpenNI libOpenNI HINTS $ENV{OPEN_NI_LIB} "/usr/lib")
LINK_DIRECTORIES($ENV{OPEN_NI_LIB})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${OPEN_NI_INCLUDE})
LINK_LIBRARIES(${OPEN_NI_LIBRARY})
FIND_PATH(XN_NITE_INCLUDE "libXnVNite.so" HINTS "$ENV{XN_NITE_INSTALL_PATH}" "/usr/include/nite")
FIND_LIBRARY(XN_NITE_LIBRARY NAMES libXnVNite_1_5_2.so HINTS $ENV{XN_NITE_INSTALL_PATH} "/usr/lib")
LINK_DIRECTORIES($ENV{XN_NITE_LIB_INSTALL_PATH} "/usr/lib")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${XN_NITE_INCLUDE})
LINK_LIBRARIES(${XN_NITE_LIBRARY})

target_link_libraries (your_project_name ${SSE_FLAGS} ${OPEN_NI_LIBRARIES} ${XN_NITE_LIBRARIES})
```

If, instead, you want to use a manually installed copy of OpenNI 2.* (not in ROS yet), please see [this discussion](http://community.openni.org/openni/topics/cmake_configuration_files_for_openni) for a starting CMakeLists.txt which solves some problems but not all. Disclaimer: this is a shameless link to a question related to OpenNI, CMake but not to ROS that I myself posted on the OpenNI forums.

---

Originally posted by [Giovanni Saponaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/595/giovanni-saponaro/) with karma: 68 on 2013-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on the CMakeLists.txt included in openni_tracker, try this:

```
include(FindPkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(OPENNI libopenni)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OPENNI_LIBRARIES})
```

---

Originally posted by [yoos](https://answers.ros.org/users/1207/yoos/) with karma: 78 on 2013-02-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kourosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/3448/kourosh/) on 2013-04-01**:
I can confirm this works under Kubuntu 12.10, ros groovy.